# Como utilizar o AWS Glue para obter dados 'por batelada' em BD semi-estruturado?

Tags: python, amazon-aws, scala, spark

É possível utilizar o AWS Glue para obter os dados de forma incremental em uma base de dados SQL semi-estruturada? Os dados *on-premise* que pretendo exportar para a nuvem AWS estão numa única tabela, com chave primária, mas sem incrementação linear dessa chave e sem data de inserção para referência. Preciso executar um *job* que executa de oito em oito horas e busque apenas os novos dados inseridos na tabela.

Comment: pq não usar o aws dms? é um serviço que vai te ajudar a migrar esses dados facilmente.